# Why is the number of location swaps showing up as zero?

Tags: c++

While I'm pretty sure the number of location swaps for everything else is correct, the one for my InsertionSort function is showing up as zero.

I'm not sure why.

Any ideas on how to fix this logic error?

```
   #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE=20;

void bubbleSort(int numbers[], int SIZE);
void selectionSort(int numbers[], int SIZE);
void insertionSort(int numbers[], int SIZE, int &a, int &b);



int main()
{
    int numbers[SIZE]= {26, 45, 56, 12, 78, 74, 39, 22, 5, 90, 87, 32, 28, 11, 93, 62, 79, 53, 22, 51};
    int value=0;
    bool found;
    int a;
    int b;

    cout << "Today we are going to be searching for values." << endl;
    cout << "These are the values you have to choose from" << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        cout << numbers[i]<<"; ";

    do
    {
        cout << "Make sure to enter a value that's in the list." << endl;
        cin >> value;
        found=false;
        for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        {
            if (value==numbers[i])
            {
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            cout << "Enter a valid value !" << endl;
    }
    while (!found);

    bubbleSort(numbers, SIZE);
    selectionSort(numbers, SIZE);
   insertionSort(numbers, SIZE, a, b);





    return 0;
}

void bubbleSort (int numbers[], int SIZE)
{
    cout<<"\nOriginal order: ";
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    cout<<numbers[i]<<' ';
    int maxElement;
    int index,counter=0;

    for(maxElement=SIZE-1; maxElement>=0; maxElement--)
    {
        for(index=0;index<=maxElement-1;index++)
        {
            if(numbers[index]>numbers[index+1])
            {
                swap(numbers[index], numbers[index+1]);
                counter++;//increments counter everytime swap occurs
            }
        }
    }
cout<<"\nBubble Sorted: ";
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    cout<<numbers[i]<<' ';
    cout<<"\nNumbers of location swap: "<<counter<<endl;
}

void swap(int &a, int &b)
{
    int temp;
    temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}

void selectionSort(int numbers[], int SIZE)
{  cout<<"\nOriginal order: ";
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    cout<<numbers[i]<<' ';
    int startScan;
    int index;
    int miniIndex;
    int miniValue;
    int counter=0;

    for(startScan=0;startScan<(SIZE-1);startScan++)
    {
        miniIndex=startScan;
        miniValue=numbers[startScan];

        for(index=startScan+1;index<SIZE;index++)
        {
            if(numbers[index]<miniValue)
            {
                miniValue=numbers[index];
                miniIndex=index;
            }

        }
        swap(numbers[miniIndex], numbers[startScan]);
        counter++;
    }
cout<<"\nSelection Sorted: ";
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    cout<<numbers[i]<<' ';
    cout<<"\nNumbers of location swap: "<<counter<<endl;
    cout << endl;
}

void insertionSort(int numbers[], int SIZE, int &a, int &b)
  {
    int temp = a; a = b; b = temp;
     int j, swap = 0;
     cout<<"Original order: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    cout<< numbers[i] << ' ';
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        j = i;

        while (j > 0 && numbers[j] < numbers[j-1])
            {
              temp = numbers[j];
              numbers[j] = numbers[j-1];
              numbers[j-1] = temp;
              j--; swap++;
              }
        }
        cout <<"\nThe number of location swaps is: "<< swap << endl;
        return;
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps because the array is already sorted because you just sorted it twice.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. 

@immibis

Comment: Insertion-sort only does a swap when the array isn't already sorted. Since the array is already sorted it does 0 swaps.

Comment: @immibis. 

Why is it doing this if the others aren't?

Comment: Because in selection sort you're counting the size of the array not the number of swaps, and in bubble sort the array isn't already sorted.

Comment: I changed all the arr[]'s in my code to numbers. Don't know how it went to arr[] in the first place. 

I'm having trouble spotting the difference between the bubble sort function and this one? @immibis

Comment: I'll start from basics... Your code sorts the array three times, correct?

Comment: Yes. My code sorts it three times.

Comment: After the first time you sort it, it is in sorted order, correct? That is, every number in the array is greater than or equal to the one before it.

Comment: Yes. Or at least I believe I understand what you're talking about.


@immibis

Comment: Okay. So when does insertion sort do a swap?

Comment: Oh! I see. That makes sense now. Haha. So I just put                        void swap(int &a, int &b)
{
    int temp;
    temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}                              at the bottom?

Comment: I have no idea how what you just said or  relates to your problem. So when does insertion sort do a swap? As in: what makes it decide to do a swap?

Comment: I have very bad reading skills, so cope with me. Um,   }
  cout <<"\nThe number of location swaps is: "<< swap << endl;
  return;
 }    down here.

Comment: @PeterFriedman: There is nothing you have to change in your code. The code is correct. The insertion sort does 0 swaps, and it is correct behavior for it to do 0 swaps. If you want it to swap, then give it an unsorted array. Try calling it first, before bubble sort. Then you will see that the number of swaps that bubble sort does is 0.

Comment: When you say give it an unsorted array, what do you mean? 

In my bubble sort I passed it the same way I did in my insertion function.@BenjaminLindley

Comment: No, I'm genuinely confused about what is being said to me. I understand how I swapped in the bubblesort and selectionsort, but I don't understand how I didn't swap in the insertionsort. Didn't I already pass the array without it being sorted? Do I add swap at the bottom? I'm not sure what's being told of me. @BenjaminLindley

Comment: *"Didn't I already pass the array without it being sorted?"* -- No. You passed it the array which was previously sorted by bubble sort. I don't understand how this is confusing to you. You asked three different functions to do the same thing (albeit in different ways). Only the first one (bubble sort) actually had to do anything. The other 2 already had the job done for them (by bubble sort). The only reason it appears that selection sort is doing anything is because the way it is structured, it calls swap on every element, even if it is swapping the element with itself.

Comment: Bubble sort and insertion sort don't do that. They never swap elements with themselves. They only swap different elements which are out of place. So if no elements are out of place, they don't swap anything.

Comment: Alright, so bubblesort and insertionsort I did correctly (they swap) or I did selectionsort wrong as well? But I didn't for insertionsort. I understand that. I now understand why I didn't pass an unsorted array. What I'm asking is how do I fix this? Is there something special I do particular for the insertionsort? @BenjaminLindley

Comment: But, it says there are zero swaps. I want it to swap. Therefore it's a logic error, right?

@BenjaminLindley

Comment: @BenjaminLindley It's the name my professor wanted me to put. I did what you told me to, but the swap is still at zero. Sorry for the silly name, haha. Thanks for being patient with me. (I edited my OP for you to see what I have now so you can comment)

Comment: I want it to swap the original array.

Comment: Then don't pass it to `bubbleSort` first. Or make two arrays with the same content, passing one to `bubbleSort`, and the other to `insertionSort`.

Comment: So, just call it first instead of bubble sort and it's all fixed? 

@BenjaminLindley

Comment: If your definition of "fixed" is that `insertionSort` swaps elements, then sure, it's "fixed". However, I suspect you will be disappointed when you find that now `bubbleSort` won't be making any swaps, for the same reason that `insertionSort` wasn't making any swaps before (that is, because now it's receiving an array that was already sorted by `insertionSort`, so it has nothing to swap).

Comment: How do I make it to where they all make swaps. 

@BenjaminLindley

Comment: I already answered that. Not going to repeat things anymore.

Comment: You said pass an unsorted array. How? @BenjaminLindley

Comment: Make an unsorted array. Pass it to the function. You've already done this once. Do you really need help figuring out how to do it again?

Comment: Not too much. Probably a little. I made an unsorted array and passed it. 

Now I'm just dealing with some errors that I don't believe are related to it. 
http://prntscr.com/c02dbo
@BenjaminLindley

Answer (score 2):

You get 0 swaps for insertion sort because insertion sort performed 0 swaps, because the array was already sorted, because you ran bubble sort on it earlier.

You don't get 0 swaps for selection sort because your selection sort function always performs N-1 swaps, if N is the size of the array, even if the array is already sorted.

You don't get 0 swaps for bubble sort because the array isn't already sorted at that point.